# why does this function translate that way with bitwise operators?

Tags: c#, bitwise-operators

I was writing a control class for a device until I got to the point I needed to convert an ARGB color into its format. at first, I wrote this function (which worked):

```
private static int convertFormat(System.Drawing.Color c)
{
    String all;

    int a = (int)((float)c.A / 31.875);

    if (a == 0)
        a = 1;

    all = a.ToString() + c.B.ToString("X").PadLeft(2, '0') + c.G.ToString("X").PadLeft(2, '0') + c.R.ToString("X").PadLeft(2, '0');

    int num = int.Parse(all, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowHexSpecifier);

    return num;
}
```

but it was so ugly I wanted to write a more elegant solution.
So I did some for to get the correct values, trying all combinations between 0 and 50.
It worked, and I ended up with this:

```
private static int convertFormatShifting(System.Drawing.Color c)
{
    int alpha = (int)Math.Round((float)c.A / 31.875);

    int a = Math.Max(alpha,1);

    return (a << 24) | (c.B << 48) | (c.G << 40) | (c.R << 32);
}
```

which works!

but now, I would love someone to explain me why these are the correct shifting values.

Comment: `int` is 32-bit signed integer in C#. So your shifts are not correct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The least confusing shift values should be as follows:

```
return (a << 24) | (c.B << 16) | (c.G << 8) | (c.R << 0);
// Of course there's no need to shift by zero  ^^^^^^^^
```

The reason your values work is that the shift operator `mod`s the right-hand side with the bit length of the operand on the left. In other words, all of the following shifts are equivalent to each other:

```
c.G << 8
c.G << 40
c.G << 72
c.G << 104
...
```

Comment: so basically just the five low-order bits matter. thanks to you I understood this for good. :D

Comment: One of the more confusing features of C#. Better than C, which makes this undefined behavior, but still, this has always struck me as weird.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_space), the RGBA format follows the following convention:

```
semantics alpha | red | green | blue
bits      31-24 |23-16|15 -  8|7 - 0
```

This is something similar to what your shifts do. You are moving the bits to the left and concatenating them with a bit wise or. And then take a look at what is your function expected to return (what's the order of the color within the `int`).

Comment: `int` is always 32 bits.